# Accessing parent component broken after Angular 7 to 10 upgrade

Tags: angular

I've just upgraded from Angular 7 to 10.
I have a pagination component which has this funciton:

```
getParentComponent() {
    return this.viewContainerRef['_data'].componentView.component.viewContainerRef['_view'].component;
}
```

This no longer works in Angular 10.
The parent component is dynamic and we need to get it so we can set a pageSize property in the parent component. This is done in this function in the pagination component:

```
getRecordPerPage() {
    this.component.pageSize = this.recordPerPage[this.componentName];
}
```

How can I access the parent component in Angular 10 so that I can set the pageSize property in it?

Comment: If it wasn't dynamic you could simply inject the parent in the child. One thing you could try is to make your parent components to extend some class so you could inject them in their children.

Comment: There are a lot of components that use this pagination component. I'm hoping for a solution that requires minimal code changes

Comment: Any solution you got?